# Django Windows IIS Fastcgi Deploy problem (wfastcgi TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, windows-server-2012

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\...", linse 847, in main
   result = handler(record.params, response.start)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

why am i getting this error ? when use runserver everything is fine but with fastcgi not work :/

OS: Windows Server 2012 
Django Version: 2.22
Environment Variables FastCGI Application Settings;

> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: website.settings 
>   PYTHONPATH: ||PROJECT_ROOT_PATH||
>   
>  WSGI_HANDLER: website.wsgi

Comment: IT looks like your `handler` is a module, and not a function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing parentheses at the end of the `WSIG_HANDLER` environment variable.

```
WSGI_HANDLER: website.wsgi()
```

If you were to use the default `wsgi_handler` from django, you would have `.get_wsgi_application()` at the end:

```
WSGI_HANDLER: django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()
```

You can check more information on this at the [wfastcgi PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/)